# Ajax PUT request sends parameter as null when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to pass these two variables to a servlet, but get an error stating that sessionid is a null string.

```
var sessionid = document.getElementById("Session-select").value;
var attendeeid = document.getElementById("Attendee-select").value;
            console.log(attendeeid + " " + sessionid);
    $.ajax({

        url: 'http://localhost:8180/Project_2_Highfield/registrations',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        method: 'PUT',
        data: {sessionid: sessionid, attendeeid: attendeeid},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (jsondata) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(jsondata));
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
             var success = jsondata['success'];
             $("#output").append("<p>"+ "Success: " + success +"</p>");
        }});
```

The error is as follows:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Cannot parse null string

I tried adding a console log to ensure the variables weren't null; they aren't, yet one still gets sent as null in the ajax query.

Here is the HTML related to this part.

```
<body>
        <fieldset >
         <legend>Session Management</legend>
          <label for="Sessions">Select Session:</label>

         <select name="Session-select" id="Session-select"> </select>
         <p></p>
         <label for="Attendees">Select Attendee:</label>

         <select name="Attendee-Select" id="Attendee-select"> </select>
         <p></p>
            <input type="button" value="List Registrations" onclick="list_session_attendees();">
            <input type="button" value="Update Registration" onclick="update_registration();">
            <input type="button" value="Cancel Registration" onclick="cancel_registration();">
      </fieldset>
</body>
```

Edit: Forgot to mention, the drop down menu it's pulling from is generated dynamically. Here is the code behind that:

```
function generate_session_list() {
 $.ajax({

        url: 'http://localhost:8180/Project_2_Highfield/training',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (jsondata) {
            
            var len = jsondata.length;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(jsondata));
                for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                           var session = jsondata[i]['description'];
                           var id = jsondata[i]['id'];
              $("#Session-select").append("<option value='"+ id +"' >"+ session +"</option>");
    }

        }});
    
}
```

I have made the other suggested changes, but am still encountering the error.

Upon further testing, this error appears to occur even when I hard-code the ID to send; i;e,

```
data: {sessionid: "1", attendeeid: attendeeid},
```

I am not sure why.

Comment: So, on load, the variable isn't null, you're sure? JavaScript captures the value once on load (probably when your `<input>` element is just still empty i.e. no one wrote anything there).

Comment: Certain. It has a value in the log, it just doesn't send with one.

Comment: Also, add the HTML code related to this part.

Comment: Open network tab in dev tools and see if the values are there

Comment: OK; also there's a small syntax error, remove `}` at the end of JavaScript. And, actually depending on the HTML code you posted, [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/6sr983xk/) returns `""` and that's `null` actually.

Comment: Try use this in your data : data: {sessionid: (!isNaN(sessionid) ? 0 : sessionid), attendeeid: (!isNaN(attendeeid) ? 0 : attendeeid)},

Comment: "The error is as follows: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Cannot parse null string" — That's a server side error, but you haven't shown us the server side code.

Comment: "Upon further testing, this error appears to occur even when I hard-code the ID to send; i;e, `data: {sessionid: "1", attendeeid: attendeeid}` I am not sure why." — Probably because **the problem is server-side**

Answer (score 0):

(I know you code snippets is out of context), but don't set the two global variables as a starting point.

Here I use two techniques to for ensuring that the form cannot be submitted before a session and a attendee has been selected. First, the submit button is disabled. I wrapped the AJAX request for session and attendee data in a promise. When the promise is returned the submit button will be enabled.

Second I made the select elements required. This means that the form can only be submitted if the session and the attendee is selected.

Often it is a good idea to avoid using IDs in a form. Use the name attribute instead. You can see that it is easy to refer to the value of one of the select elements in the context of the submit event callback (`put_registration(e)`).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  generate_session_list();
  document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', put_registration);
});

function put_registration(e) {
  // submit event callback
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = e.target;
  $.ajax({
    url: 'data:application/json,{"success":"Registration submitted"}',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    method: 'PUT',
    data: {
      sessionid: form.sessionselect.value,
      attendeeid: form.attendeeselect.value
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(jsondata) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(jsondata));
      form.output.value = jsondata['success'];
    }
  });
}

function generate_session_list() {
  let form01 = document.forms.form01;
  let promise1 = $.ajax({
    url: 'data:application/json,[{"id":1,"description":"Session01"},{"id":2,"description":"Session02"}]',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(jsondata) {
      // remove all options except the first
      while(form01.sessionselect.item(1)){
        form01.sessionselect.remove(1);
      }
      // add new options
      jsondata.forEach(session => {
        let opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.value = session.id;
        opt.text = session.description;
        form01.sessionselect.add(opt, null);
      });
    }
  }).promise();
  let promise2 = $.ajax({
    url: 'data:application/json,[{"id":1,"description":"Attendee01"},{"id":2,"description":"Attendee02"}]',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(jsondata) {
      // remove all options except the first
      while(form01.attendeeselect.item(1)){
        form01.attendeeselect.remove(1);
      }
      // add new options
      jsondata.forEach(attendee => {
        let opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.value = attendee.id;
        opt.text = attendee.description;
        form01.attendeeselect.add(opt, null);
      });
    }
  }).promise();
  // enable submit button when session and attendee has been fetched
  $.when(promise1,promise2).then(function(){
    form01.submitBtn.disabled = false;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form01">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Session Management</legend>
    <label for="Sessions">Select Session:</label>

    <select name="sessionselect" required>
      <option value="">Select a session</option>
    </select>
    <p></p>
    <label for="Attendees">Select Attendee:</label>

    <select name="attendeeselect" required>
      <option value="">Select an attendee</option>
    </select>
    <p></p>
    <!--<input type="button" value="List Registrations" onclick="list_session_attendees();">
    <input type="button" value="Update Registration" onclick="update_registration();">
    <input type="button" value="Cancel Registration" onclick="cancel_registration();">-->
    <button name="submitBtn" type="submit" disabled>Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
  <output name="output"></output>
</form>
```

Comment: Good thinking, but I know it has already fetched the other two; the values display in console log

Comment: You write that the two variables are set, but you code is not reproducible, so we cannot help you except that we can try to teach you good way of writing your code. Maybe I'm not solving your issue, but please read my code and see you you can learn something and then implement that.

Answer (score -1):

It's weird when you say that you go both variable logged in console but one of them is sent as null.
Try to add a condition to only execute the ajax code when both variables are not null.

```
var sessionid = document.getElementById("Session-select").value;
var attendeeid = document.getElementById("Attendee-select").value;
            console.log(attendeeid + " " + sessionid);
if(attendeeid.trim().length != 0 && sessionid.trim().length != 0) {
    $.ajax({

        url: 'http://localhost:8180/Project_2_Highfield/registrations',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        method: 'PUT',
        data: {sessionid: sessionid, attendeeid: attendeeid},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (jsondata) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(jsondata));
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
             var success = jsondata['success'];
             $("#output").append("<p>"+ "Success: " + success +"</p>");
        }});
   }
}
```

If the Ajax code is not executed, then for sure one of your variables is null or empty, in this case you can check why the select is not getting a value.

Comment: The `value` property can *never* return a `null` value.

Comment: True, but the code is always viable cause it also check for empty string : ""

Comment: The ajax code executes, it's just that it sends a null value when it shouldn't. If it didn't send anything, then I wouldn't have the parsing error from the servlet.

Comment: If even after adding the condition below, the ajax code still executing, then probably the error is on the backend.